# permission access denied in laravel4.2 in linux

Tags: linux

I am using Ubuntu  when i have installed my project in opt/lampp/htdocs folder it is restricting that some folders permissions denied. when am trying to run the command chmod -R 644 app/storage it is showing that :

```
user@host:~$ chmod -R 644 app/storage
chmod: cannot access 'app/storage': No such file or directory
```

when i try to run the project it is showing that :

```
file_put_contents(/opt/lampp/htdocs/bazaa/app/storage/sessions/7b2822ce03a7f890afe496675cd269695c3bb1e8): failed to open stream: Permission denied
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below command

```
user@host:~$ sudo chmod -R 644 path/to/your/file
```

You missed adding sudo before your command.

Comment: `sudo` is barely the answer to `No such file or directory`.

Answer (score 0):

You should provide the full path to chmod. `chmod -R 644 /opt/lampp/htdocs/bazaa/app/storage` in your case.

To explain, your current directory is "~", which is typically /home/user. However, the folder with permission errors is located in /opt/lampp/htdocs/bazaa/app/storage. So when you run chmod in ~ using a relative path, it is running against /home/user/app/storage; not your intended path of the LAMPP setup.